# Sql Server Management Studio Express 2008 - How do I assign Ctrl-N to open new query window?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

It would appear that the functionality to add shortcut keys in SSMS2008 is mostly implemented, however, I don't seem to be able to shortcut key to anything.

For example,

Tools --> Customize --> Commands --> File --> New Query

Clicking on New Query and pressing the "Keyboard..." key simply opens up the Options screen. (In most MS IDE's, this will facilitate shortcut creation.)

In Options --> Environment --> Keyboard there is a list of Query Shortcuts, but I don't see any way to add shortcuts here.

Any thoughts?

Comment: btw, an argument can be made that this belongs on Serverfault, superuser, or here. I use it as a programming IDE for SQL code. Had to compromise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options 
select Environment -> keybord
from Keyboard Schema drop down, select "SQL Server 2000"
select OK.
Then again, go to that option and select back "Standard". You will get Ctrl+N and F8 keys.

See this post:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2008/08/26/missing-f8-or-ctrl-n-in-ssms-2008.aspx